# Given a 6 blocks, of different height h1, h2 . Make 2 towers using 3 Blocks for each tower in desired height h1, h2

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
elemnts=[2,2,5,6,7,3]
h1=12
h2=13


def func(elemts,a,b):
list1=[]
for i in range(0,len(elemts)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(elemts)):
        for k in range(0,len(elemts)):
            if(k not in [i,j]):
                temp=elemts[i]+elemts[j]+elemts[k]
                if(temp==h1|temp==h2):
                    list1.extend([elemts[i],elemts[j],elemts[k]])
                    return list1
list2=func(elemnts,h1,h2)
```

'this functions is for finding those 3 variables.once i find any set,i return the values'

```
'am not getting desired result for different inputs.if the input is 
[2,2,0,0,5,6] and heights [9,6],the output is empty'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to get the indentation and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) right (and to include the contents of your comment).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Also remember to research before you post.  This *problem* is solved in several places on line and on this site.  If your problem is with your code in particular, then you'll need to describe that for us.

Comment: @Prune...is it okey now??

Comment: @Prune...is it okey now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elemnts=[2,2,0,0,5,6]
h1=9
h2=6


def func(elemts,a,b):
list1=[]
for i in range(0,len(elemts)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(elemts)):
        for k in range(0,len(elemts)):
            if(k not in [i,j]):
                temp=elemts[i]+elemts[j]+elemts[k]
                if(temp in [h1,h2]):
                    list1.extend([elemts[i],elemts[j],elemts[k]])
                    return list1
list2=func(elemnts,h1,h2)
```

@arthur_currry...just chnged one line in last if case.Its working fine